# mongoengine- what do referencefield store

Tags: mongodb, orm, mongoengine

In mongoengine what value must be set into ReferenceField. I mean should we provide in "ObjectId" of the document to which the reference is to be made.
For example,

```
class Bar(Document):
    content = StringField()
    foo = ReferenceField('Foo')
```

The object of class Bar should have what value set to in "foo" attribute. Should it be the ObjectId of some document in 'Foo' collection?
Also can I set any other unique field as a value in reference field mentioning which field it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's stores a DBRef, you just need to pass a Foo instance and it will be converted automatically. See the section in the docs: https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.io/guide/defining-documents.html?highlight=referencefield

Comment: thanks mate, I guess they have updated their docs for version 0.6.20. I was using 0.6.18, though I will update it 0.6.20 Thanks a lot for the help friend.

Comment: link is dead, 404

Answer (score 12):

Before MongoEngine version 0.8, it stores a DBRef by default.  For 0.8 and later, it stores an ObjectId by default.

There's a `dbref` parameter that you should use when creating the ReferenceField ([explicit is better than implicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)):

```
class Bar(Document):
    content = StringField()
    foo = ReferenceField('Foo', dbref = True)   # will use a DBRef
    bar = ReferenceField('Bar', dbref = False)  # will use an ObjectId
```

Here's the [documentation for the ReferenceField](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.io/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.ReferenceField).

I have version 0.7.9 installed, and when I create a ReferenceField *without* the `dbref` parameter, I get the following warning:

```
[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/fields.py:744: FutureWarning:
ReferenceFields will default to using ObjectId  strings in 0.8, set DBRef=True
if this isn't desired
warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning)
```